# How can I enter Setup without keyboard?

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, bios

After replacing a power supply my computer will not boot.  The message is USB devises total: 0 Drive, 0 keyboard, 0 mouse, 0 hub.
Then "Please enter setup to recover BIOS settings.  No keyboard detected!   Press F1 to run Setup.
Mouse and keyboard are USB, and I cannot get past this point.

I have tried to boot w/o hard drives, removing CMOS battery (replacing after 15 min) and using a USB keyboard connected with a USB - PS2 adapter all to no avail.
Any suggestions on how to correct the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe the type of machine ? (Desktop vs Laptop, model and year). For desktop USB, use primarily onboard ports (back). Sometimes, keyboard and mouse have "preferred" ports (the 2 closest to Power Supply).